# Detecting a gate underwater composed of different colors

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am participating in an Underwater Robotics Competition and the first task is to make AUV(Autonomous Underwater Vehicle) pass through a gate. The gate is composed of three colors - [Image of gate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qhm2O.png)

I have tried implementing a simple program to convert the image to grey scale and then use canny edge detection. The problem is that the yellow side is ignored by the edge detector. Moreover, the gate isn't exactly a rectangle, that is the bottom part is not exactly a pole.

I have also tried using the HSV color scheme to try and extract colors but this wouldn't work because colors get distorted underwater.

Any suggestions on what I should do?

Comment: Take multiple pictures underwater to get the color values for the gate. Then set  ranges based on that data set. If you want to go overboard with it, you could implement a learning algorithm.

Comment: This is way too broad. What have you tried codewise? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: It's good when posting a question to be ready to put a small program that you have attempted along with the desired goal(s).  BTW, your rectangle can be described by the yellow bottom and side...take a bunch of images and figure out how to threshold the yellow-ish colour and you'll have a good start.

Comment: This seems a bit too broad at the moment. It's not clear to me why you are doing this edge detection, I think you need to explain your overall plan an thought process here. Also, what exactly is your code responsible for in the end? Is it just a detection that you plug in some sort of SLAM at the end, or something more complete?

Comment: It seems to me that the gate is coloured in that unusual fashion for a reason, and that the yellow colour is the first thing that catches your eye. I think that converting to greyscale as the first step and discarding all that information is probably an error...

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust a sensor in your robot at proper centre of you robot and set any distance of sensor that if any device come into there range then it will change its direction and also if it come in the centre of your gate then it will move in simple way